# How to solve error when default_target_path is included in Security.yaml?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm getting the error which surprises me because in below security.yaml file

```
     default_target_path: createEvent
```

is giving me an error.
If I include default_target_path: createEvent in security.yaml I get

```
The file "E:\Symfony\myproj\config/packages/security.yaml" does not contain valid YAML in E:\Symfony\myproj\config/packages/security.yaml (which is loaded in resource "E:\Symfony\myproj\config/packages/security.yaml").
```

If I remove default_target_path then it is working well, but I'm unable to redirect after login.

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: uname


firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login   
            default_target_path: createEvent

        logout: 
            path: /logout
            target: /login    
access_control:
     - { path: ^/login/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: The error message says that the YAML config is not valid. In the example from your question every line starting with the second one needs to be indented.

Comment: Yea I can agree with you ,but the indent is correct in the file. I posted wrong in here.  It is correct in project.

Comment: Well, the error message is clear here: `E:\Symfony\myproj\config/packages/security.yaml` does not contain valid YAML. You can use an online parser like http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and paste your config file there. Maybe it helps you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your path name `createEvent` is correct in your controller and add this in `security.yml` file

```
form_login:
    login_path: login
    check_path: login_check
    always_use_default_target_path: false
    default_target_path: YOUR_PATH_NAME
logout:
    path: logout
    target: login
```